Debian passwd package sources - Unable to find patch that modifies passwd utility options
I noticed passwd utility doesn't support the -s/--stdin option on Debian which allows to read password from standard input. With this option you can do something like echo mypassword | passwd -s mylogin to set password for specific login from script.
I just wanted to try it but noticed it is not possible on Ubuntu nor Debian which is base for Ubuntu. It will print error that option is not recognized.
So i went to Debian sources for passwd package (it's here https://salsa.debian.org/debian/shadow/-/tree/master/debian?ref_type=heads) and tried to find the patch that removes the option because in the original source code for passwd utility the option is still there (https://salsa.debian.org/debian/shadow/-/blob/master/src/passwd.c?ref_type=heads#L166).
I can't find the patch in the repository, it looks like it's not there. Can anybody help me to find it? I don't know the workflow that is used to patch the original source code but i expected the patch to be there because there is folder with patches (https://salsa.debian.org/debian/shadow/-/tree/master/debian/patches/debian?ref_type=heads).
Thank you.

You could consider using chpasswd instead

@steeldriver: yeah i know, i want to know what i am missing because i want to understand how the option could disappear. It must be some patch but where? Why it is not part of the repo or did i miss something? Still trying to figure it out but without any result.

So i finally found where is the "problem". I thought that this -s/--stdin options is part of passwd utility for years (i am new to serious Linux understaning).
Actually it was implemented this year (2024) according to upstream on github (https://github.com/shadow-maint/shadow/commit/49001ca846d1e2894b4719d66889ab7e1b4b698a).
Debian 12 codenamed bookworm passwd package is built upon older sources (branch 4.13 https://salsa.debian.org/debian/shadow/-/blob/upstream/4.13+dfsg1/src/passwd.c?ref_type=tags). I checked just master branch where the change is already included.
Nevermind atleast i learned something new.
